# Nuget - create package with NativeReference for unregistered dlls

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

I want to use nuget with a manifest file that includes unregistered com dlls.
When adding this manifest file to a project it will be added to

But just adding this manifest file to the nuspec document and packing it won't work.
I hope someone has a clue for me how to get this to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ALM115</id>
    <version>11.52.584.0</version>
    <authors>asdf</authors>
    <description>ALM 11.5 paket
     ALM_OTAOnly.sxs.manifest
    </description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="ALM_OTAOnly.sxs.manifest"/>    
  </files>
</package>
```

//Dietrich